# Polygon Filling Algorithm for Polygons with crossing Lines in C

Tags: c, algorithm, graphics

I have this implementation of my polygon filling algorithm:

```
//point in polygon algorithm for filling polyons
void fill_polygon(Array *vx,Array *vy){
    int  nodes,  pixelX, pixelY, i, j, swap,polyCorners ;
    double top,bot,right,left,nodeX[1000];
    polyCorners = vx->used;
    if(polyCorners<=2){
        return;
    }
                /*printf("Soltado VX: Used(%d) \n",vx->used);
                for(i=0;i<vx->used;i++){
                    printf("|%d|", vx->array[i]); 

                }
                printf("\n VY: Used(%d) \n",vy->used);
                for(i=0;i<vy->used;i++){
                    printf("|%d|", vy->array[i]); 

                }       
                printf("\n");
                wait(35);   */
    bot = maximum(vy);
    top = minimum(vy);
    right = maximum(vx);
    left = minimum(vx);
    /*printf("Top %d  - Bot %d - Left %d - Right %d \n",top,bot,left,right);
    wait(40);*/
    for (pixelY=top; pixelY<bot; pixelY++) {

        //  Construyendo lista de Nodos de la figura
        nodes=0; j=polyCorners-1;
        for (i=0; i<polyCorners; i++) {
            if (vy->array[i]< (double)pixelY && vy->array[j]>=(double)pixelY
                ||  vy->array[j]<(double) pixelY && vy->array[i]>=(double)pixelY) {

                nodeX[nodes++]=(vx->array[i]+(pixelY-vy->array[i])/(vy->array[j]-vy->array[i])*(vx->array[j]-vx->array[i])); 

            }
            j=i; 
        }   
        //  Ordenamos nodos con bubble sort
        i=0;
        while (i<nodes-1) {
            if (nodeX[i]>nodeX[i+1]) {
              swap=nodeX[i]; nodeX[i]=nodeX[i+1]; nodeX[i+1]=swap; if (i) i--; 
            }

            else {
              i++; 
            }
        }
     // Rellenamos pixeles entre los nodos
        for (i=0; i<nodes; i+=2) {
            if   (nodeX[i]>=right) break;

            if   (nodeX[i+1]> left ) {
                if (nodeX[i  ]< left ) nodeX[i  ]=left ;
                if (nodeX[i+1]> right) nodeX[i+1]=right;
                for (pixelX= (int)nodeX[i]; pixelX<nodeX[i+1]; pixelX++){

                    plot_pixel(pixelX,pixelY,current_color);
                }  
            }
        }       

    }
}
```

It is working fine for normal polygons but it is not filling the polygons as it should when I have a crossing polygon like the one below. (The rightis the un filled polygon, the leftis the result of my algorithm.

[image]

When the result should be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: It looks like your filling method is a little simplistic for the polygons you want to fill. You should look up the "odd-even" rule and the "winding number" rule for filling polygons. Those should help you on your journey.

Comment: Is your description correct? Did you mean *"The **right** is the un filled polygon, the **left** is the result of my algorithm"*? And BTW does your algorithm work with **concave** polygons?

Comment: Sorry I made the edits. And I haven´t tested it with concave polygons but it´s not necessary to make it work with those kinds if polygons

Comment: I don't understand why you think it's unnecessary to make the algorithm work with concave polygons, before you attempt the next more complex polygon with crossings.

Comment: Well I think you might be more knowledgable than me but  I said that because the way I construct the polygon is just giving it a list of points which represent each of the straight lines of the polygon. I always assume that between point A and B there will be the minimum distance possible.

Comment: I think there's an _off-by-one_ error in `for (i=0; i<nodes; i+=2)`. I think it should be `for (i=0; i<nodes-1; i+=2)`. Otherwise, the accesses to `nodeX[i+1]` in the loop would be invalid for the final iteration if `nodes` is odd.

Comment: For each row, order the points from each edge that intersects that row.  Then just iterate over the points, keeping track of the parity.  If the parity is odd, render the point.  If it's even, don't.  Simple.